# Batch file name and line counts in Windows

Tags: windows, file, cmd

I am writing file names of all files in a directory by using the command below.

```
cmd /c dir /s /b /a:-d E:\SportsData /b /a:-d > E:\outputs\FileStats.txt
```

I also need line counts of each file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You specified the `dir` switches `/b` and `a:-d` twice. Why are you preceding the command line with `cmd /c`? And what do you mean by "each file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R E:\SportsData %%f in (*) do (
    SET CurrentFile=%%f
    SET /a NumLines=0
    For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< !CurrentFile!') Do Set /a NumLines=%%j
    ECHO !CurrentFile! has !NumLines! lines.
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: thank you! this writes file names and counts onto screen

Answer (score 1):

```
    Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
    Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        Count = Count +1
    Loop
    outp.writeline Count
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo c:\folder\vbsfile.vbs < inputfile
```

Gives this result

```
C:\Windows\system32>cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\lc.vbs" < ..\win.ini
15
```